# How to make a class label shown as the column name of the class?

Tags: rdf, sparql

The SPARQL

```
SELECT ?c0 ?l0
WHERE 
{ 
  ?c0 rdf:type <XXXX>.
  OPTIONAL
  {
    ?c0 rdfs:label ?l0.
  }
}
```

shows two columns `c0` and `l0`. Any way to show only one column `c0`,but with the content of the `?l0` as the title of the `?c0` ?  The result would look like *select ?co as* ...

Comment: What should happen if there are many values for `?l0`? The way you wrote the query, there may be at least one different value of `?l0` for each `?c0`.

Comment: Possibly related [question on answers.semanticweb.com](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/15445/how-to-set-the-label-of-a-column-nameheader-as-in-sparql).

Comment: What's the matter with `select ?co { ?x a <XXXX> . optional { ?x rdfs:label ?co } }`?  It sounds like you just want to (i) use a different variable for the label (easy) and (ii) not select the variable bound to the thing (easy). Is there something else to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can do this with **coalesce**, which returns its first non-error bound argument. First, here's some data where there's a class **:dog** with the label **"Dog"**, and a class **:cat** which has no label:

```
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix : <http://example.org/> .

:dog a rdfs:Class ;
     rdfs:label "Dog" .
:cat a rdfs:Class .
```

Here are the query and results:

```sql
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select (coalesce(?label,?class) as ?co) where {
  ?class a rdfs:Class
  optional {
    ?class rdfs:label ?label
  }
}
```

```
----------------------------
| co                       |
============================
| <http://example.org/cat> |
| "Dog"                    |
----------------------------
```