# SPARQL replace empty attributes with others

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I made a SPARQL query using the official DBpedia endpoint.

I'll take it for example for the main Question:

```
SELECT  ?museum ?EnglishAbstract   ?RussianAbstract 
WHERE { 

?museum dbpedia-owl:abstract ?EnglishAbstract. 
?museum a dbpedia-owl:Museum.
filter(lang(?EnglishAbstract)='en')

optional{
    ?museum dbpedia-owl:abstract ?RussianAbstract.
    ?museum a dbpedia-owl:Museum.
filter(lang(?RussianAbstract)='ru')
}}
GROUP BY ?museum
```

With this query (that works good), I find for every row (`museum`) a bunch of Abstract in 2 languages: English and Russian.
The Russian abstracts are present only if available because I use "OPTIONAL".
Obviously I get a lot of empty attributes.

I would replace the blank attribute with the English abstract (always present).

Reading the W3C SPARQL page, I found that there is a particular testing value that is true when a variable is set: Bound

I would like to write something like this:

```
If Bound (?RussianAbstract), "?RussianAbstract", "?EnglishAbstract"
```

-->  if `RussianAbstract` is present, hold it; else, put the `EnglishAbstract` instead of it.

Does anyone know how can I make it work?

Comment: You may find [Generating values for empty attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19723721/1281433) useful, as well as [SPARQL : how to make a class label shown as the column name of the class?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26114572/1281433), which actually addresses using one value if another isn't available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to use [`COALESCE`](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-coalesce):

```
SELECT  ?museum (COALESCE(?RussianAbstract, ?EnglishAbstract) as ?Abstract)
```